# Prolog Syntax Error in ubuntu

Tags: prolog

I have been trying to solve the problem BST(Binary search tree)
For eg:-

```
checkBST(t(6; t(4; t(2; nil; nil); t(5; nil; nil)); t(9; t(7; nil; nil); nil))):
true:
```

My code is working in windows but in ubuntu it is showing syntax error. Here is my code.

```
checkBST(nil).
checkBST(t(X,L,R)):-
   checkBSTs(L,L1),
   checkBSTs(R,R1),
   ( R1==null -> true ; X<R1 ),
   ( L1==null -> true ; X>L1 ).
checkBSTs(nil,X):-
   X=null.
checkBSTs(t(X,L,R),X1):-
   X1 is X,
   checkBSTs(L,L1),
   checkBSTs(R,R1),
   ( R1==null ->  true ; X<R1 ),
   ( L1==null ->  true ; X>L1 ).
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to write `t(2; nil; nil)` which is invalid syntax &mdash; and not `t(2, nil, nil)` ?